# insert image in latex

Tags: latex

I tried to insert image in latex. I first uploaded images to sidebar of overleaf. And then I used such code

```
We still first focus on totally random dataset.\\ 
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{aab.png}
\caption{aab\label{thename}}
 \end{figure}



Then we focus on partially random dataset.\\ 
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{abb.png}
\caption{abb\label{thename}} 
\end{figure}
 



At last we look at true dataset. 
\begin{figure}[h] 
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{aba.png} 
\caption{aba\label{thename}} \end{figure}
```

And then But what I got is [image]

There images are all in wrong positions, they all appear after texts, but they are supposed to be inserted between the texts. Where the issue comes from?

Comment: Don't abuse `\\ ` for line breaks!

Answer (score 0):

`\begin{figure}[h!]`instead of `\begin{figure}[h]` would be the best choice. But you can also use `\begin{figure}[H]` but you need to add the `float` package.

Please see:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_images_and_tables, the section under `figure environment` educates the different parameters and their meaning under figure environment.

Answer (score 0):

The `figure` environment is meant to float, which means that latex will find a good place for it. You should write your text in such a way that you expect specific positions for the images. Instead you can references them by their number in the text. This method works best if you have a bit more text than in your example, so I added a bit of random text in the example below so you can see how this works.

If you don't want this, you shouldn't use a figure environment. instead you could use the `\captionof` macro to add captions to your non-figure images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\section{The latex way:}

At first, we focus on a totally random dataset, depicted in figure \ref{thenamea}. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{aab\label{thenamea}}
 \end{figure}
 After that we focus on partially random dataset as shown in figure \ref{thenameb}. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{abb\label{thenameb}} 
\end{figure}
At last we look figure \ref{thenamec} which is the true dataset.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
\begin{figure}[htbp] 
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-duck} 
\caption{aba\label{thenamec}} 
\end{figure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\clearpage
\section{No floats}


We still first focus on totally random dataset.

{
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\captionof{figure}{aab\label{thenameaa}}
}


Then we focus on partially random dataset.

{
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\captionof{figure}{abb\label{thenamebb}} 
}
 

At last we look at true dataset. 

{
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-duck} 
\captionof{figure}{aba\label{thenamecc}} 
}


\end{document}
```